# If $A=A^T$ with positive eigenvalues and $B$ is invertible, then $B^T A B$ is symmetric with positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I want to prove the following:

> Suppose matrices $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same dimension. If $A$ is symmetric and has positive eigenvalues and matrix $B$ is invertible, show that matrix $B^T AB$ is symmetric and has positive eigenvalues.

---

$\textbf{Proof}$: It is trivial to show symmetry, as
$$(B^TAB)^T=B^TA^T(B^T)^T=B^TAB$$
which follows from the symmetry of $A$. For $A$ to have positive eigenvalues, it must be psoitive definite, meaning $\pmb{x}^TA \pmb{x}>0, \forall x$. Suppose that $\pmb{x}$ is an eigenvector of matrix $B^TAB$. It follows that

$$B^TAB\pmb{x}=\lambda \pmb{x}$$

Multiplying by $\pmb{x}^T$,
$$\pmb{x}^TB^TAB\pmb{x}=\lambda \pmb{x}^T \pmb{x}$$
$$(B\pmb{x})^TA(B\pmb{x})=\lambda \| \pmb{x} \|^2.$$
Suppose that $B\pmb{x}=\pmb{y}$. Then,
$$\pmb{y}^TA\pmb{y}=\lambda \| \pmb{x} \|^2>0$$
as $\pmb{y}^TA\pmb{y}>0$ since $A$ is positive definite/has positive eigenvalues.

I feel like my proof is correct, but what makes me question it is that I did not use the invertiblity of matrix $B$. Any thoughts/comments on my proof?

Comment: You are presuming that $Bx \neq 0$ above (which is true when $x \neq 0$, since $B$ is invertible).

Comment: @copper.hat so If i simply state that, my proof should be fine?

Comment: Well, you should understand the point in the proof where you are assuming that $x \ne 0$ implies $Bx \neq 0$.

Comment: I would add that when you write $x^TAx>0$, this should be for all $x\neq 0$. This is a small note, since you only use it for $x\neq 0$ (since $x$ is an eigenvector).

Comment: Why is the question downvoted? It's well formatted, context is given, and the OP shows effort. Yes, it's a dupe (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1175585/443030), but the OP asks for proof verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line of reasoning would establish positive definite if you were to note that $Bx$ is nonzero for all nonzero $x$, because $B$ is invertible.

Without noting the invertibility of $B$ however, what you have established is that $B^{\top}AB$ is positive *semidefinite*.

Comment: So adding in the proof that $Bx \neq 0$ as $B$ is invertible should suffice to complete the proof?

Comment: Yes that is correct